# React Native can't set timouts properly in async functions

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I've got the following action:

```
const someAction = async () => {

    // t=0s: logs 'one'
    console.log('one');

    // wait 1000ms for the promise to resolve
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

    // t=1s: logs 'two'
    console.log('two');

    // will log 'three' at t=2s
    setTimeout(() => console.log('three'), 1000);

}
```

In a plain browser, the behavior is the same as the one described in the comments. However, when running on my Android phone, the three logs happen almost immediatly, in the order 'one', 'two', 'three'. What is happening? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

---

Update: three related issues ([#22620](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22620), [#22620](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22620) and [#22620](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22620)) seem to point out in the direction that there is a React Native bug for setTimeouts when using devtools)

Comment: Try to blame it on `setTimeout` (instead of promises or async/await syntax) by trying to code it the old way (callback style)

Comment: Doesn't work either, cf issue 22620

Comment: @NinoFiliu the comments in the linked issues all point to the problem existing when the debuger tools/console is open. Have you tested with the debug tools closed?

Comment: No, because I have to log many things while developing the current feature. I cannot possibly "develop blindly".

Comment: @NinoFiliu Ah, you probably should post those three issues as an answer to this queston

Comment: React Native is notorious for giving you hard-to-diagnose race conditions when you have the debugger connected